# Avoid sorting using immutable.js

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

To me Immutable.js reduces a lot of headaches and it's a great library, but now im facing with a trouble, my original object comes from the server but when I use any of it's functions like `fromJS({myObj})` it works but saves a copy but sorted "a-z" and I'm making something that need the original structure to keep the components in the order that comes from the server, someone any Idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Javascript core objects explicitly provide no guarantees about key order. `Immutable.Map` (the expected result of your `fromJS()` call) just follows that.

If you want order, you should either specify the order as another property on each item, or, more conventionally, create an `Immutable.List` from an `Array`.

In other words, this sounds like a square peg/round hole problem. Make sure you're using the right data structure for your task.

Comment: I tried using Immutable.List and i got the same result, anyway thanks.
Here is an example
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/normanfx/sdufb9ac/)

Comment: @Norman Your code is close. The object properties will not keep their order. If you want items to have an order, you need to store them in a `List`: `var myOrderedObj = Immutable.fromJS({ name: 'thing', orderedProps: [{ size: 1}, { weight: 2}] })`. This is kind of a strange thing to do, however.

Comment: :/ well, I think I'll start something with that :) thanks Trevor.

Comment: No problem. I know the answer is sort of unsatisfying.

Comment: No it's ok, I have a sort of solution but when it is finished I'll write it here.

Answer (score 3):

`fromJS` translates your objects into `lists` and `maps` by default. The former is ordered but not keyed, while the latter is keyed but not ordered, so neither fits your use case.

What you're looking for is an `OrderedMap`, which is a `Map` with an additional insertion order guarantee:

```
import { OrderedMap } from 'immutable';
const orderedMap = OrderedMap({key: "value"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by still using `fromJS`: It has a second parameter called [reviver](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/fromJS), which can be used also for using OrderedMaps instead standard Maps:

```
import Immutable from 'immutable';
const reviver = (key, value) => 
    Immutable.Iterable.isKeyed(value) ? value.toOrderedMap() : value.toList();
const data = Immutable.fromJS(js, reviver);
```